# Windows Console2 coolType

Tags: c++

As you can see in u413.com: Text comes on the screen, letter by letter, which looks kind of cool,

I want to do the same thing in [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

I got the source code of version **1.2**; because I dont need all the complexity of version 2;
I just need a simple Command Prompt, with text that comes on to the screen letter by letter.
I dont need most of the builtin functions offered by Console, like Transparency, Taskbar Icon, etc.

The source code base is pretty small with only about 5 files.

The main class file seems to be Console.cpp;

Since console is like a GUI application, things dont get written to the STDOUT.

but heres what happens;

A Handle is called;
And that handle apparently writes to the console;

```
m_hStdOut   = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

Now what I want to be able to do; Is somehow read the handle; see what text it has; And throw in a loop with a ::Sleep(20) method in it; to make sure that text appears letter by letter.

---

@Alf P. Steinbach I wrote the psuedo code for making the sleep command(in java) I also made use of it in every other java program I wrote, but the disadvantage was that it will work only for my programs and not every program run in the command prompt, but what I dont know is code to make a console, a windows console subsystem program, I wish it was possible with java, so that I could use it on linux too, but now, let me ask you exactly what I had in mind...

A program which simply, took input from the screen, send it to cmd.exe for processing, and sent back the reply, and all I have to do is throw in a sleep command between every character...

All I need is help, in getting this done, I wish you could start me up with this, and possible provide links and refrences to get this done...

Comment: what's your question? and what's that half-of-it web reference? anyway, the assertion "things dont get written to the STDOUT" is most probably incorrect

Comment: my question is - how do I implement the feature? like making text appear letter by letter, I want to know how I can read the content of the handle(m_hStdOut)

Comment: ¤ A Console is meant for running ordinary console programs. You don't need to deal with the Console source code. You can just create an ordinary Windows console subsystem program (which is the default for all extant Windows C++ compilers), and you can then run it either in an ordinary Windows console window, or in a Console window. To read text from a console window's buffer you can use the [`ReadConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. To output you can use the `WriteConsole` function. And use `Sleep` to sleep. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: can you please explain furhter with possilble links and help?
because id really like it if you there were more help...
can you also give sample code?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach can you help me with sample code?
sorry for tagging you...

Comment: he he {http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ}. anyways, in pseudo-code, `for_each( ch in s ) { write( ch ); sleep( 250); }` where you define `write` to call `WriteConsole`. Cheers,

Comment: btw, this method to show text(letter by letter) is kinda annoying. I just wait and think:"COME ON, WHY U NO FAST?"

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach I wrote the psuedo code for making the sleep command(in java),what I dont know is code to make a console, a windows console subsystem program, I wish it was possible with java, so that I could use it on linux too, but now, let me ask you exactly what I had in mind...

A program which simply, took input from the screen, send it to cmd.exe for processing, and sent back the reply, and all I have to do is throw in a sleep command between every character...

Answer (score 0):

This Console.cpp seems like a console emulator, meaning it runs OTHER programs. You don't need the source code, you can run existing console applications.

STD_INPUT_HANDLE, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE and STD_ERROR_HANDLE are the windows handles for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. They basicly does the same with only a few differences in how to use it.

If you want to integrate the console into your code, then you have to understand it, and find its own output function and call that. But it won't be any standard handle or things like that.

Comment: Console.cpp being a emulator was exactly what I need, I need that program to run everything I enter in cmd.exe.

as you can see from my question:
m_hStdOut is the handle, but heres the catch...
that handle, is used only thrice in the whole Console.cpp program and not once can I see characters being echoed to the screen!